# RHOM Find Conditions (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, find, conditional-statements, rhomobile, rhom

I have two Models, `ELTeam` and `Rider` which are linked by the attribute `ELTeamID`.

I am trying to parse the value `ELTeamID` via the

```
<%= url_for :action => 'filter_rider_by_team', :id => team.ELTeamId %>
```

My method is:

```
def filter_rider_by_team
    rId = @params['id'] 
    rId = rId.sub(/{/,'') 
    rId = rId.sub(/}/,'') 

    #variable
    @riders = Rider.find(:all, :conditions => {'ELTeamId' => '#{rId}'})

    #hardcoded
    #@riders = Rider.find(:all, :conditions => {'ELTeamId' => '3'})

      Rho::Notification.showPopup({
      :message => "Parameter ID: #{@params['id']}, rId: '#{rId}', Riders: #{@riders}",
      :title => "Riders",
      :buttons => ["OK"]
      })
end
```

If I use the line beneath `"variable"` I get nothing returned ([output of showPopup here](http://www.thisisspeedway.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/variable.png)), however, if I use the line under #hardcoded I get a Rider returned ([output of showPopup here](http://www.thisisspeedway.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/hardcoded.png)).

What is the correct syntax to pass through the value as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do interpolation, use double quotes: `"#{rId}"`, which is equivalent to `rId.to_s`. Since you seem to have a string as `rId`, you should just write `rId`.

Comment: Bloody hell, thanks! I've been playing around with this for nearly two days! Thanks.